# How to store big image in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckasset

I tried to upload a picture to `CloudKit`, and store it as `NSData`, but with a relatively bigger picture, taken with camera, I get this error:

```
Error saving record <CKRecordID: 0x15998770; 04359DFA-8370-4000-9F53-5694FC53FA9C:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> to server: record too large id=04359DFA-8370-4000-9F53-5694FC53FA9C of type UserSetting
```

What is the maximum size of data is able to store in `CloudKit`?

How do you store big images taken with camera in `CloudKit`?

I tried with two image, and I plotting out size of them.

```
let d = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
println("d.length: \(d.length)")
```

- `d.length: 55482` <- works
- `d.length: 17614327` <- does not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should store pictures as a CKAsset. For a CKRecord there is a size limitation. For a CKAsset there is not (beside the CloudKit storage limitations). According to the documentation:

> Use assets for discrete data files. When you want to associate images
>   or other discrete files with a record, use a CKAsset object to do so.
>   The total size of a record’s data is limited to 1 MB though assets do
>   not count against that limit.

You can create a CKAsset like this:

```
var File : CKAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("image-not-available", ofType: "jpg")!))
```

Comment: From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKAsset_class/index.html) : *The files or data you save using an asset object must be no larger than 250 MB.*

Comment: Is there any way to create a URL from an image? I have the user choose between clicking the image within the app or using a UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Edwin, If you can look  at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186769/records-zone-doesnt-displayed-in-dashboard-and-delete-zone-issue-cloudkit)  and  help me, please