# How to get URL from UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, image, url, cloudkit

I have an iOS app in which there are 2 ways the user can get a picture:

1. Select it from photos library (`UIImagePickerController`)
2. Click it from a custom made camera

Here is my code for clicking the image from a custom camera (this is within a custom class called `Camera`, which is a subclass of `UIView`)

```
func clickPicture(completion:@escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {

    guard let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)  else { return }

    videoConnection.videoOrientation = .portrait
    stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (sampleBuffer, error) -> Void in

        guard let buffer = sampleBuffer else { return }

        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
        let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData! as CFData)
        let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)

        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1, orientation: .right)

        completion(image)


    })
}
```

Here is how I click the image within the `ViewController`:

```
@IBAction func clickImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    cameraView.clickPicture { (image) in
        //use "image" variable
    }
}
```

Later, I attempt to upload this picture to the user's iCloud account using `CloudKit`. However I receive an error saying the record is too large. I then came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817807/5143847), which says to use a `CKAsset`. However, the only constructor for a `CKAsset` requires a `URL`.

Is there a generic way I can get a `URL` from any `UIImage`? Otherwise, how can get a `URL` from the image I clicked using my custom camera (I have seen other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085409/getting-url-of-uiimage-from-uiimagepickercontroller) about getting a url from a `UIImagePickerController`)? Thanks!

Comment: How would I create a temp location URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CKAsset` represents some external file (image, video, binary data and etc). This is why it requires `URL` as init parameter.

In your case I would recommend to use following steps to upload large image to CloudKit:

1. Save `UIImage` to local storage (e.g. documents directory).
2. Initialize `CKAsset` with path to image in local storage.
3. Upload asset to Cloud.
4. Delete image from local storage when uploading completed.

Here is some code:

```
// Save image.
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!
let filePath = "\(path)/MyImageName.jpg"

UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)!)
// Upload asset here.

// Delete image.
do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filePath)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, I am obtaining the following error while saving the record to CloudKit: "No such file or directory". What could be causing this?